# Firebase functions - admin.firestore() get() throws auth error on local serving

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, firebase-cli

I have a firebase cloud function, which gets the data from the cloud firestore.

```
const userSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user).get()
```

when this api is deployed locally using `firebase emulators:start`.

I get the following error:

```
The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running so database operations will fail with a 'default credentials' error.
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
>  Auth error:Error: invalid_grant
```

This is happening only after updating the firebase-tools.
Previously it was working fine using `firebase serve --only function --port=9000`.
In this tools version I am not able to set the port through command line.

Comment: Please post your issue on the Firebase emulator GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Hi! Can you ensure you're running `firebase-tools@6.9.1`, this was a known issue in `6.9.0`

Comment: It is in 6.9.1 version but still the error exists

Comment: In a bug they had asked to delete application_default_credential.json from ~/.config/gcloud. After, I got this error:The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running so database operations will fail with a 'default credentials' error.
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
>  Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved in 6.9.2

We can use firebase serve with port number to access firestore.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1265